# Tasks or ThreadPool to handle http requests?

Tags: c#, task, threadpool

I recently upgraded a personal project I've been working on to use the .Net framework 4.5. While updating my app, and taking advantage of the new Async and Await features, i thought about also improving my custom made internal Http Server that uses the ThreadPool to process the request and send the response back to the client. Would it be better to use tasks instead?

Here is my current code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Accepts the connection
/// </summary>
private static void DoAcceptClientCallback(IAsyncResult Sync)
{
    try
    {
        // Finish accepting the client
        HttpListenerContext Context = Listener.EndGetContext(Sync);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(HandleRequest, new HttpClient(Context));
    }
    catch (HttpListenerException E)
    {
        // Thread abort, or application abort request
        if (E.ErrorCode == 995)
            return;

        ServerLog.Write("ERROR: [DoAcceptClientCallback] \r\n\t - {0}\r\n\t - ErrorCode: {1}", E.Message, E.ErrorCode);
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        ServerLog.Write("ERROR: [DoAcceptClientCallback] \r\n\t - {0}", E.Message);
    }

    // Begin Listening again
    if(IsRunning) 
        Listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(DoAcceptClientCallback), Listener);
}

/// <summary>
/// Handles the Http Connecting client in a new thread
/// </summary>
private static void HandleRequest(object Sync)
{
    /// ... Processing Stuff is done here to serve the page back to the client
}
```

Comment: `Task` is just a tool that allows asynchronous operation, such as requests to run a method in a thread pool thread, to be performed differently.  It's designed to be easier to use.  Whether you actually prefer it or not is a decision *you* need to make.  If *you* like it better, then use it.  If you don't, then don't.

Comment: Note that if you're already using a framework such as ASP.NET, it will handle requests on your behalf and manage the threading infrastructure.

Comment: Its a winform desktop application

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes but just because Task is more modern. There is no fundamental difference between the threadpool and `Task` (assuming you mean CPU-based tasks).

A more important optimization would be to make `HandleRequest` async. Your use of async IO for `GetContext` does not add one bit to scalability. The request processing must be async, not the accepting.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I thought EndGetContext was an Async operation?

Comment: Yes, that's async. Not sure what you're saying. HandleRequest is not using async IO, at least it does not look like it.

Comment: Oh ok, i see what you mean now, Thank you :)